# restarting authconfig changes order of my /etc/nsswitch.conf

Tags: linux, ldap, pam, pam-ldap

Here is my nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:     files ldap sss
shadow:     files ldap sss
group:     files sss
```

When I restart authconfig, it removes ldap from passwd, shadow, and group.

Here's my authconfig.

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --disablenis --enablecachecreds --   disableldaptls --enablelocauthorize --ldapserver=127.0.0.1 --enableshadow --ldapbasedn="dc=wh,dc=local" --enablesssd --updateall
```

Where do I go to configure and make sure ldap will stay in the nsswitch.conf when I restart authconfig?

Answer (score 1):

I changed one of the options in the authconfig command.

I changed --updateall to --update

It doesn't affect my /etc/nsswitch.conf anymore.